# PhoneGap onDeviceReady not firing

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm new to phonegap so I just tried something out and was starting with the onDeviceReady method. The problem I'm encountering is, that the method doesn't fire.

This is my complete code, pretty basic.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Splashscreen Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    $("#texttest").css("display", "none");
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="texttest" style="display:block">text</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So now, when the app is launched the text should be hidden right? Well, the entire div should, but the device still shows me the "text". What am I doing wrong there? I also tried some other basic methods like

```
$("#texttest").hide()
```

but that didn't work either. This is the MainActivity.java

```
    package de.activevaluetenthousandfliesphonegap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have the correct version of cordova.js for the platform you are targetting.
Also what version of Phonegap are you using ?

Comment: Sorry, have added it of course. But it still didn't work. I'll update the initial post.

Comment: Okay - you need to make sure you have the Android version of Cordova in your JS. This can be found in your Phonegap SDK - e.g. ...phonegap-2.7.0/lib/android/cordova-2.7.0.js. You also need the project Android set up to use the Cordova jar library.

Comment: Yep, did exactly that. Followed the tutorial on their site and only included the android files

Comment: And your cordova.js isn't in your js folder ?

Comment: Correct. It's in the same folder as the index.html

Comment: I thin what is happening is that you need jQuery to complete its load then use deviceready. So do this: $(document).ready(function(){ ...  ( See my other answer )

Answer (score 1):

Please try removing the font-awesome, if included. They have some compatibily issues with its css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

I had the same problem once and solved when I removed the above line from my code,

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Splashscreen Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}


function onDeviceReady() {
    $("#texttest").css("display", "none");
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
       <div id="texttest" style="display:block">text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope, still not working... No change of the text/div

Comment: Add your cordova js file like:<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-2.4.0.js" charset="utf-8" ></script>

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think you need to do:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    }
```

Because when your device ready triggers jQuery hasn't loaded - this will ensure you do the following:
1. Get jQuery
2. Trigger PhoneGap deviceready

Also remove your `onLoad()` function ! :)

Comment: Thanks to that edit, but I also did this. And it still didn't help. I will try it at home again. Maybe it will work then. The classic turn on/turn off ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is working on my ripple emulator. But I use `jquery-1.9.1.js` and `cordova 2.7` ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all You need to test it as an application in the emulator/mobile and not on the web browser. Secondly if you want to use geolocation then you can use it like this

```
function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("we are an app");
        MyApp.initialize_phonegap();
      }

      function onBodyLoad() {   
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      }

    </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="onBodyLoad()">
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the cordova.js shared by my colleague who is an iOS developer. I replaced that with the latest cordova.js from the Cordova site and it started to work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

After creating your app using cordova, the index.js (or build.js) contains something like

```
var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
```

in the default event handler function "receivedEvent".

These lines only work fine for the Hello-World-Dummy of Cordova. As soon as you replace the content of the index.html "parentElement" will be undefined. That leads to a javascript error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
at Object.receivedEvent (index.js:37)
at Object.onDeviceReady (index.js:31)
at Channel.fire (cordova.js:846)
at cordova.js:231
```

The index.html of the cordova Hello-World contains a container

```
<div id="deviceready" class="blink">
```

As soon as you remove this, the build of the app failes with the mentioned JavaScript-Error.

You can simply replace the lines above with something like

```
if (id=="deviceready")
{
    console.log("addEventListener for backbutton");
    $("#texttest").css("display", "none");
    // ... whatever
}
```